# How does Realm handle deleting fields with links?

Tags: realm

Let's say that I have a Realm object with a link. So, using the Realm examples, something like:

```
public class Person extends RealmObject {
  public RealmList<Dog> dogs;
}
```

What happens when I call person.deleteFromRealm? Is the dog owned by that person deleted as well? Does it depend on the exact data setup? The documentation isn't clear here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`person.deleteFromRealm()` only deletes the object you're calling it on.

To delete the associated elements inside a link, you must call `dogs.deleteAllFromRealm()` on it (before deleting the `person`).

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the inner list first help, solve the problem for you. Happy coding. So do `dogs.deleteAllFromRealm()` first and then act on `person` next